# PHP Script to Get Latest Post Featured Image and Link form WP blogs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 (Wordpress) blogs on the same server and a landing page with 2 images. 
One goes to first blog, the next one to the second blog.
Is there any way I can get in the first image, the post-thumbnail and link from the first post from the first blog and same thing from the second blog for the other image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say, you have blog at:

- http://example.com/ which resides on `/home/username/example.com/`
- http://example12.com/ which resides on `/home/username/example12.com/`

and you have landing page at:

- http://example31.com/ which resides on `/home/username/example31.com/index.php`

You will need to create 2 files:

- /home/username/example31.com/index.php
- /home/username/example31.com/index_test_wordpress.php

And both will have code, something like this:

1. on your `/home/username/example31.com/index.php`, write:

   ```
   <?php
   echo file_get_contents('http://example31.com/index_test_wordpress.php');
   require_once("/home/username/example12.com/wp-load.php");
   echo  str_repeat("<br />", 10);
   $posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array('numberposts'=>1, 'post_status'=>'publish') );
   print_r($posts);
   ?>
   ```
2. on your `/home/username/example31.com/index_test_wordpress.php`, write:

   ```
   <?php
   require_once("/home/username/example.com/wp-load.php");
   $posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array('numberposts'=>1, 'post_status'=>'publish') );
   print_r($posts);
   ?>
   ```

Note:

1. I use `file_get_contents` to that file because I can't figure out a way to do two require() to wp-load.php, without conflicting each functions.
2. For simplicity's sake, I only put `print_r($posts)`. But, you should get the idea.

Comment: Ok, I tested this and it gives me all data except the post thumbnail url... :((((! Do you have any ideea? The image is setted!